# Deployment error on Laravel 5.1 on Amazon Server EC2

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2

I try to deploy my laravel code ( works locally ) in Amazon EC2 with Envoyer script.
I get this error:

```
Using global Composer installation.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v1.1.1)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Downloading: 0%                   Downloading: 55%        Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v2.7.6)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Downloading: 0%                   Downloading: 5%        Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading:     60%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading:     95%    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing symfony/translation (v2.7.6)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Downloading: 0%                   Downloading: 5%        Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 15%    Downloading:     20%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading:     35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading:     45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading:     55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading:     65%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading:     80%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading:     90%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing symfony/routing (v2.7.6)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Downloading: 0%                   Downloading: 5%        Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 15%    Downloading:     20%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading:     35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading:     45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading:     55%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading:     70%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading:     80%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading:     90%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing symfony/process (v2.7.6)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Downloading: 0%                   Downloading: 35%        Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading:     85%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v2.7.6)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download symfony/http-foundation from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v2.7.6)
    Cloning 7598eea151ae3d4134df1f9957364b17809eea75

  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.7.6)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download symfony/event-dispatcher from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.7.6)
    Cloning 87a5db5ea887763fa3a31a5471b512ff1596d9b8

  - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download psr/log from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
    Cloning fe0936ee26643249e916849d48e3a51d5f5e278b

  - Installing symfony/debug (v2.7.6)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download symfony/debug from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/debug (v2.7.6)
    Cloning fb9e6887db716939f41af0ba8ef38a1582eb501b

  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v2.7.6)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download symfony/http-kernel from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v2.7.6)
    Cloning 4260f2273a446a6715063dc9ca89fd0c475c2f77

  - Installing symfony/finder (v2.7.6)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download symfony/finder from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/finder (v2.7.6)
    Cloning 2ffb4e9598db3c48eb6d0ae73b04bbf09280c59d

  - Installing symfony/dom-crawler (v2.7.6)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download symfony/dom-crawler from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/dom-crawler (v2.7.6)
    Cloning 5fef7d8b80d8f9992df99d8ee283f420484c9612

  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v2.7.6)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download symfony/css-selector from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v2.7.6)
    Cloning e1b865b26be4a56d22a8dee398375044a80c865b

  - Installing symfony/console (v2.7.6)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download symfony/console from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/console (v2.7.6)
    Cloning 5efd632294c8320ea52492db22292ff853a43766

  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.1)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download swiftmailer/swiftmailer from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.1)
    Cloning 0697e6aa65c83edf97bb0f23d8763f94e3f11421

  - Installing nikic/php-parser (v1.4.1)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download nikic/php-parser from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing nikic/php-parser (v1.4.1)
    Cloning f78af2c9c86107aa1a34cd1dbb5bbe9eeb0d9f51

  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (0.1)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download jakub-onderka/php-console-color from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (0.1)
    Cloning e0b393dacf7703fc36a4efc3df1435485197e6c1

  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.3.2)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.3.2)
    Cloning 7daa75df45242c8d5b75a22c00a201e7954e4fb5

  - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (0.1)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (0.1)
    Cloning 265b8593498b997dc2d31e75b89f053b5cc9621a

  - Installing psy/psysh (v0.5.2)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download psy/psysh from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing psy/psysh (v0.5.2)
    Cloning aaf8772ade08b5f0f6830774a5d5c2f800415975

    Skipped installation of bin bin/psysh for package psy/psysh: name conflicts with an existing file
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (1.0.10)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download paragonie/random_compat from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (1.0.10)
    Cloning 2fa50aa2f17066fa74ba00d943e8cee1a98284af

  - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.20.0)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download nesbot/carbon from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.20.0)
    Cloning bfd3eaba109c9a2405c92174c8e17f20c2b9caf3

  - Installing mtdowling/cron-expression (v1.0.4)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download mtdowling/cron-expression from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing mtdowling/cron-expression (v1.0.4)
    Cloning fd92e883195e5dfa77720b1868cf084b08be4412

  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.17.2)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download monolog/monolog from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.17.2)
    Cloning bee7f0dc9c3e0b69a6039697533dca1e845c8c24

  - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.15)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download league/flysystem from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.15)
    Cloning 31525caf9e8772683672fefd8a1ca0c0736020f4

  - Installing jeremeamia/superclosure (2.1.0)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download jeremeamia/SuperClosure from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing jeremeamia/superclosure (2.1.0)
    Cloning b712f39c671e5ead60c7ebfe662545456aade833

  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.0.1)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download doctrine/inflector from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.0.1)
    Cloning 0bcb2e79d8571787f18b7eb036ed3d004908e604

  - Installing danielstjules/stringy (1.10.0)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download danielstjules/stringy from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing danielstjules/stringy (1.10.0)
    Cloning 4749c205db47ee5b32e8d1adf6d9aff8db6caf3b

  - Installing classpreloader/classpreloader (2.0.0)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download classpreloader/classpreloader from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing classpreloader/classpreloader (2.0.0)
    Cloning 8c3c14b10309e3b40bce833913a6c0c0b8c8f962

  - Installing laravel/framework (v5.1.23)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download laravel/framework from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing laravel/framework (v5.1.23)
    Cloning a4ea877d2bb6a68796b244a741594968796c1c4e

  - Installing illuminate/html (v5.0.0)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download illuminate/html from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing illuminate/html (v5.0.0)
    Cloning 3d1009bb8e0f25720c914af5c1f4015dd373c9ef

  - Installing webpatser/laravel-countries (dev-master e29dcce)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download webpatser/laravel-countries from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing webpatser/laravel-countries (dev-master e29dcce)
    Cloning e29dcce821f2c4a522e35483c38632ca534db4ee

  - Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.5.0)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download fzaninotto/faker from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.5.0)
    Cloning d0190b156bcca848d401fb80f31f504f37141c8d

  - Installing hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v1.2.2)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download hamcrest/hamcrest-php from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v1.2.2)
    Cloning b37020aa976fa52d3de9aa904aa2522dc518f79c

  - Installing mockery/mockery (0.9.4)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download mockery/mockery from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing mockery/mockery (0.9.4)
    Cloning 70bba85e4aabc9449626651f48b9018ede04f86b

  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (2.0.4)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (2.0.4)
    Cloning d68dbdc53dc358a816f00b300704702b2eaff7b8

  - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (1.4.8)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download phpunit/php-token-stream from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (1.4.8)
    Cloning 3144ae21711fb6cac0b1ab4cbe63b75ce3d4e8da

  - Installing symfony/yaml (v2.7.6)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download symfony/yaml from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v2.7.6)
    Cloning eca9019c88fbe250164affd107bc8057771f3f4d

  - Installing sebastian/version (1.0.6)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download sebastian/version from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing sebastian/version (1.0.6)
    Cloning 58b3a85e7999757d6ad81c787a1fbf5ff6c628c6

  - Installing sebastian/global-state (1.1.1)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download sebastian/global-state from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing sebastian/global-state (1.1.1)
    Cloning bc37d50fea7d017d3d340f230811c9f1d7280af4

  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (1.0.1)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download sebastian/recursion-context from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (1.0.1)
    Cloning 994d4a811bafe801fb06dccbee797863ba2792ba

  - Installing sebastian/exporter (1.2.1)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download sebastian/exporter from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing sebastian/exporter (1.2.1)
    Cloning 7ae5513327cb536431847bcc0c10edba2701064e

  - Installing sebastian/environment (1.3.2)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download sebastian/environment from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing sebastian/environment (1.3.2)
    Cloning 6324c907ce7a52478eeeaede764f48733ef5ae44

  - Installing sebastian/diff (1.3.0)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download sebastian/diff from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing sebastian/diff (1.3.0)
    Cloning 863df9687835c62aa423a22412d26fa2ebde3fd3

  - Installing sebastian/comparator (1.2.0)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download sebastian/comparator from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing sebastian/comparator (1.2.0)
    Cloning 937efb279bd37a375bcadf584dec0726f84dbf22

  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download phpunit/php-text-template from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1)
    Cloning 31f8b717e51d9a2afca6c9f046f5d69fc27c8686

  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.5)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download doctrine/instantiator from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.5)
    Cloning 8e884e78f9f0eb1329e445619e04456e64d8051d

  - Installing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (2.3.8)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (2.3.8)
    Cloning ac8e7a3db35738d56ee9a76e78a4e03d97628983

  - Installing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.7)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download phpunit/php-timer from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.7)
    Cloning 3e82f4e9fc92665fafd9157568e4dcb01d014e5b

  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.4.1)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download phpunit/php-file-iterator from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.4.1)
    Cloning 6150bf2c35d3fc379e50c7602b75caceaa39dbf0

  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (2.2.4)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download phpunit/php-code-coverage from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (2.2.4)
    Cloning eabf68b476ac7d0f73793aada060f1c1a9bf8979

  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (v1.5.0)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download phpspec/prophecy from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (v1.5.0)
    Cloning 4745ded9307786b730d7a60df5cb5a6c43cf95f7

  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (4.8.16)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download phpunit/phpunit from dist: Could not authenticate against github.com
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (4.8.16)
    Cloning 625f8c345606ed0f3a141dfb88f4116f0e22978e

    Skipped installation of bin phpunit for package phpunit/phpunit: name conflicts with an existing file
symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-symfony_debug ()
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or any loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)
symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/browser-kit ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/class-loader ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command requires SQLite to work.)
paragonie/random_compat suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides a modern crypto API that can be used to generate random bytes.)
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
monolog/monolog suggests installing raven/raven (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing videlalvaro/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v2)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v3)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-azure (Allows you to use Windows Azure Blob storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Flysystem adapter decorator for metadata caching)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-copy (Allows you to use Copy.com storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-dropbox (Allows you to use Dropbox storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-eventable-filesystem (Allows you to use EventableFilesystem)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Allows you to use Rackspace Cloud Files)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Allows you to use SFTP server storage via phpseclib)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-webdav (Allows you to use WebDAV storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-ziparchive (Allows you to use ZipArchive adapter)
laravel/framework suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Required to use the SQS queue driver and SES mail driver (~3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing doctrine/dbal (Required to rename columns and drop SQLite columns (~2.4).)
laravel/framework suggests installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (Required to use the Mailgun and Mandrill mail drivers (~5.3|~6.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing iron-io/iron_mq (Required to use the iron queue driver (~2.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Required to use the Flysystem S3 driver (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Required to use the Flysystem Rackspace driver (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pda/pheanstalk (Required to use the beanstalk queue driver (~3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing predis/predis (Required to use the redis cache and queue drivers (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pusher/pusher-php-server (Required to use the Pusher broadcast driver (~2.0).)
fzaninotto/faker suggests installing ext-intl (*)
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock suggests installing dflydev/markdown (~1.0)
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock suggests installing erusev/parsedown (~1.0)
sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (>=2.2.1)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (~1.1)
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Warning:  require(/home/ubuntu/kendo/releases/20151104174638/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /    home/ubuntu/kendo/releases/20151104174638/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/ubuntu/kendo/releases/20151104174638/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/    share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/ubuntu/kendo/releases/20151104174638/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  Error Output: PHP Warning:  require(/home/ubuntu/kendo/releases/20151104174638/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file     or directory in /home/ubuntu/kendo/releases/20151104174638/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17                    
  PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/ubuntu/kendo/releases/20151104174638/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr    /share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/ubuntu/kendo/releases/20151104174638/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17  



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-    progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "illuminate/html": "^5.0",
        "webpatser/laravel-countries": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "bin-dir": "bin",
        "vendor-dir": "vendor/composer"
    }
}
```

I've also tried to deploy with circleCI, and same result :(
I've already did composer dump-autoload

I've given permission to my app folder.

Any Idea?

Comment: can you post content of your composer file? Also try composer dump-autoload?

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to give 777 permissions to your bootstrap and storage folders

Answer (score 0):

> Could not authenticate against github.com

This could be related to GitHub rate limits being reached. Specify your GitHub API token to avoid it.

For example by the following command:

```
composer config --global github-oauth.github.com <TOKEN>
```

or inside your `composer.json` file:

```
{  
  "config": {
    "github-oauth": {
      "github.com": "<TOKEN>"
      }
    }
}
```

See: [API rate limit and OAuth tokens](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#api-rate-limit-and-oauth-tokens) page and related [GH-3542 issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3542#issuecomment-67623002).

> Skipped installation of bin bin/X for package X/Y: name conflicts with an existing file

If you believe that message causing any issues, check the current value of `bin-dir` by `composer config bin-dir` command. If it is incorrect, make sure to `unset COMPOSER_BIN_DIR` shell variable before running `composer` command, since it will override your `composer.json`'s `bin-dir`.

---

For any other issues, please check the [Troubleshooting page](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md).